# Python: Split dictionary values into terms and make dictionary out of it

Tags: python, dictionary

I have file which consists of numbers - document id`s; and text - document:

> 1000 The world`s end
>
> 1001 This is fine

**Need to create term dictionary and postings list.**
Term dictionary represents documents, just split into terms and paired with the document id. Term dictionary should be, i`m guessing (key: term, value: document_id) Like this:

> the = 1000
>
> world`s = 1000
>
> end = 1000
>
> this = 1001
>
> is = 1001
>
> fine = 1001

Postings list represents in which documents is the term located in. Should look like this:

> This = 1000 1001
>
> the = 1000 1001
>
> first = 1000

I succeeded only by splitting document into terms (don`t even know if i did it right). What and how to do next step?

### Python code

```
#Open and read documents file
docLine = codecs.open('sample.txt', 'r', 'utf8').read().splitlines()

#Empty dictionary
doc_dictionary = {}

#Split every line in id (keys) and documents (val) to save as dictionary
for document in docLine:
    (key, val) = re.split(r'\t+', document)
    doc_dictionary[key] = val
print("Documents")
print(doc_dictionary)

#Splits documents into words (terms)
print("") 
print("Words")
words = {key: [(val) for val in value.split()] for key, value in doc_dictionary.items()}
print(words)
```

### Result

> Documents {
>
> > '1000': 'The Project Gutenberg EBook of Pride and Prejudice, by Jane Austen',
> >
> > '1001': 'This eBook is for the use of anyone anywhere at no cost and with almost no restrictions whatsoever. You may copy it, give it away or re-use it under the terms of the Project Gutenberg License included with this eBook or online at www.gutenberg.org', etc.
>
> Words {
>
> > '1000': ['The', 'Project', 'Gutenberg', 'EBook', 'of', 'Pride', 'and', 'Prejudice,', 'by', 'Jane', 'Austen'],
> >
> > '1001': ['This', 'eBook', 'is', 'for', 'the', 'use', 'of', 'anyone', 'anywhere', 'at', 'no', 'cost', 'and', 'with', 'almost', 'no', 'restrictions', 'whatsoever.', 'You', 'may', 'copy', 'it,', 'give', 'it', 'away', 'or', 're-use', 'it', 'under', 'the', 'terms', 'of', 'the', 'Project', 'Gutenberg', 'License', 'included', 'with', 'this', 'eBook', 'or', 'online', 'at', 'www.gutenberg.org'],

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would loop through the dictionary you created:

```
result = {}
for key, list in words.items():
    for elem in list:
        if elem in result:
            if not key in result[elem]:
                result[elem].append(key)
        else:
            result[elem] = [key]
```

I tried it with

```
words = {'1000': ['the', 'world', 'the'],
         '1001': ['the', 'party']}
```

and the result:

```
{'the': ['1000', '1001'], 'world': ['1000'], 'party': ['1001']}
```

to search a list of terms in the result dictionary you can use this:

```
for word in to_find:
    if word in result:
        print(word + ': ' + " ".join(result[word]))
    else:
        print(word + ': not found in dict')
```

an example input: `to_find = ['the', 'party', 'car']` gives this output:

> the: 1000 1001
>
> party: 1001
>
> car: not found in dict

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That`s what I needed! Only problem is that id`s duplicate, because in some rows of the file there are 2 sentences and that means term could be in that sentence too. For example: 1003 He is here to party. He goes ways.
'He': [1003 1003]. Term duplicates.

Comment: Thank you! Fixed it! Maybe I could ask you for the last thing? How to search a term in "result" dictionary, if i import term list (terms to search are being imported)?

Comment: tell me if I understood correctly and I'll edit my answer: you have a list of term that you want to search in the result dictionary and get the sentences where they appear. Is this correct? @Morningshade

Comment: Yes! The output should be:
project = xxx1 xxx2
the = xxx1 xxx3

Comment: @Morningshade there you have it

Comment: THANK YOU! Month of struggle and stress just to get this working,  made in few hours! Thank you again! If I have any further questions, is it ok to message you?

Comment: yeah cool, but ask it first publicly so every one gets a chance to answer! You're welcome, I'm glad I helped you!

Answer (score 1):

From your question it seems like you are trying to swap keys and values of the newly generated `dict`. This is called **indexing**, which is what you see at the back of books and how search engines deliver results fast.

Instead of creating multiple dictionaries, you can do it in one iteration by:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def normalize(line, pattern=re.compile(r"\W*\s+\W*")):
    # Use pattern to split line and trim non-word characters and set to lowercase
    return map(str.lower, pattern.split(line.strip(".!+,")))

index = defaultdict(set)
for document in docLine:
    key, value = re.split(r'\t+', document, 1)  # Split line into key and text parts
    for word in normalize(value):               # Normalize words to be used as index
        index[word].add(key)                    # Add key to word's set
```

## Output

> ```
> {'almost': {'1001'},
>  'and': {'1001', '1000'},
>  'anyone': {'1001'},
>  'anywhere': {'1001'},
>  'at': {'1001'},
>  'austen': {'1000'},
>  'away': {'1001'},
>  'by': {'1000'},
>  'copy': {'1001'},
>  'cost': {'1001'},
>  'ebook': {'1001', '1000'},
>  'for': {'1001'},
>  'give': {'1001'},
>  'gutenberg': {'1001', '1000'},
>  'included': {'1001'},
>  'is': {'1001'},
>  'it': {'1001'},
>  'jane': {'1000'},
>  'license': {'1001'},
>  'may': {'1001'},
>  'no': {'1001'},
>  'of': {'1001', '1000'},
>  'online': {'1001'},
>  'or': {'1001'},
>  'prejudice': {'1000'},
>  'pride': {'1000'},
>  'project': {'1001', '1000'},
>  're-use': {'1001'},
>  'restrictions': {'1001'},
>  'terms': {'1001'},
>  'the': {'1001', '1000'},
>  'this': {'1001'},
>  'under': {'1001'},
>  'use': {'1001'},
>  'whatsoever': {'1001'},
>  'with': {'1001'},
>  'www.gutenberg.org': {'1001'},     # Notice no trailing period.
>  'you': {'1001'}}
> ```

Please see my [Repl](https://repl.it/repls/GoodnaturedMintcreamNonagon) with complete example.

This makes use of [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) which ensures that every new key is of a specific type (in this case, a `set`). to set up the main dictionary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But now I`m facing a problem where I need to search for the term by importing file with 5 random terms. How can I search in a set?

Comment: @Morningshade Just like any other list. If you're searching for one item in a set, you can just use the `in` operator such as `if item in set_name`, if you're searching for multiple, then convert the multiple items into a set and you can use [set operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) to get your results!

Comment: Ok. When I`ll have some free time I will try :)